# Xcode Analyzer reports leak with ARC - advice on how to resolve?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, static-analysis

I'm sure the static analyser is probably right in this case, but I don't quite understand why...

Here's a segment of code from a UUID class:

```
@interface UUID {
    CFUUIDRef uuidRef;
}
@end

@implementation UUID

- (id) initWithString:(NSString*)string {
    if (string && [NSNull null] != (NSNull*)string)
        return [self initWithCFUUID:CFUUIDCreateFromString(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef) string)];
    else
        return nil;
}

- (id) initWithCFUUID:(CFUUIDRef)uuidRef {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self->uuid = uuidRef;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Xcode has reported a leak on the 'return' line in the first init.  A screenshot can be found [here](http://i43.tinypic.com/2uny5n6.png).

I have a basic understanding of bridge, bridge_retain, and bridge_transfer, but I believe bridge to be the right choice in this case.

If my understanding is correct, can anyone advise as to whether I am doing this incorrectly?  Also, how would I go about resolving this?

Regards,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `dealloc` to your implementation, and call CFRelease on `uuidRef` there:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    CFRelease(uuidRef);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand this.  If the CFUUIDCreateFromString() function returns an object with a retain count of +1, then surely releasing would deallocate it?  If I add this into my code, then it crashes, as I would expect...?

Comment: In your `UUID` class, your `-initWithCFUUID:` method should retain the `CFUUIDRef`. You should also override `-dealloc` and release the `CFUUIDRef` there. This is just the basic retain/release convention.

Comment: @dark_perfect Oops, I did not pay attention to how you kept the `UUID` object by passing it to the `initWithCFUUID`. The `self->uuid = uuidRef;` line should probably be `self->uuidRef = uuidRef;`, too, assuming that the declaration of the interface is correct (there's no `uuid` member there). I replaced my answer with something that should work.

Comment: @KurtRevis Ok, that makes sense, I suppose.  I guess I was taking shortcuts by not retaining and releasing properly and the analyser was picking me up on it.  One thing I don't get is why this hasn't shown as a leak in the profiler?  These UUID objects are created (and used) all over the app, but the profiler doesn't detect any leaks - and bearing in mind that I wasn't calling CFRelease in the dealloc method, I don't understand why?

Comment: @dark_perfect I do not know why the profiler didn't show this as a leak: `CFUUID` doc says that `CFUUIDCreateFromString` follows the "create" ownership rule.

Comment: The leak checker isn't perfect, unfortunately. I'm sure there's a reason why it didn't notice these leaks, but it's probably a pretty obscure reason.